# Can I make a scrollbar interactable through an overlaid picture?

Tags: html, css, twine

I have a CSS related question regarding scrollbars.

I have an image overlaying my jQuery-Tabbed phone on the Left and get almost all the active elements, buttons, links & inventory to still be interactive via changing the Z-Index.

However I cannot for the life of me get the ScrollBar to scroll up and down the Y-overflow of Tab 2 even though it has the correct Z-index for all it's elements.
Does someone know a way to make the ScrollBar interactive?

(i'm using w3Schools' [Custom ScrollBar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp))

My scrollbar CSS is exactly the same as the example except for added z-indexes to all elements.

(This is for a Twine 2, Sugarcube 2 Interactive Game)

```css
/* Scroll Bar */
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Track */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #6c3b00;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Handle */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #be7200;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Handle on hover */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b30000;
    z-index: 10;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em auto;
    z-index: 10;
}
.scroll-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 295px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 10;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .4em;
    z-index: 10;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar,
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    overflow: visible;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    z-index: 10;
}
.cover-bar {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    ;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: .4em;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
.scroll-bar-wrap:hover .cover-bar {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Scroll Bar */
```

```html
<h2>Custom Scrollbar Example</h2>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The -webkit-scrollbar is not supported in Firefox or in Edge, prior version 79.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
```

Code I used for the picture:

```
<div id="lcphonecover"><img style="width:220px; pointer-events: none;" src="tf95twineditor/images/Backgrounds/phonecover04oragne.png"></div>
```

[Here's my example issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE11J.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not supply the code used to overlay the image, I cannot show you the code to actually achive this, but only give you a general idea.

You can use `pointer-events: none` in CSS and apply that to your overlay image. If browsers honor it, any mouse pointer event received on the image will instead be passed to the object undernerath it.

If your image is in another DOM object, which also overlays the scrollbar, it might be necessary to apply the CSS rules to that object as well.

Comment: Regarding your edit in the question, supplying the code for the image: As I said - you must apply the pointer-events rule to the div as well in this case, as the div will be overlaying the scrollbar as well. And if the div is inside another element, same applies for that. You need to apply it to every element that is above the scrollbar - and none of them can be clicked anymore aftewards (not any links either, for example).

Comment: Thank You Johannes, That did it perfectly.
I appreciate the trick very much.